# Borel Cantelli and convergence almost surely

Tags: almost-everywhere, borel-cantelli-lemmas

I was wondering if it's possible to use the Borel Cantelli Theorem in order to ensure that the almost sure convergence DOESN'T exist.
We know that:

Let $A_n$ be a sequence of events in a probability space. If $\sum_{n=1} P(A_n) < \infty$, then $P(A_n i.o.) = 0$, implying that there is the convergence almost surely.

But what If I can find that $\sum_{n=1} \mathcal{P}(A_n) = \infty$?

I'll explain with an example:

Let ${X_n}$ be a sequence of independent random variables such that:
$$
\
X_n =
\begin{cases}
       1  \text{with probability} = \frac{1}{n} \\
      0  \text{with probability} = 1 - \frac{1}{n}
    \end{cases}\
$$

In this case, since the E($X_n) = \frac{1}{n}$ and V($X_n) =  \frac{1}{n}$, by using the chebyshev inequality:

$\mathcal{P}(X_n > \epsilon) \leq \frac{1}{n\epsilon^2}$. But $\sum \frac{1}{n\epsilon^2}$ diverges to $\infty$.

**Question:** Is it possibile to assert that the convergence almost surely it's not possibile or the fact that $\mathcal{P}(A_n)$ is not bounded has no meaning?

Comment: Second Borel-Cantelli Lemma: If $A_i$ are independent events, then $\sum P(A_i) = \infty$ implies $A_i$ occurs i.o. with probability 1.

Comment: So the answer is, yes, I can immediately conclude that there's no converge almost surely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your example: we know that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(X_n=1) = \infty$ and that $\{X_n\}$ are independent. We can use second Borel-Cantelli lemma to get that $\mathbb{P}(\limsup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\{\omega:X_n(\omega)=1\})=1$, so there is no convergence to $0$ almost surely.

Comment: Thanks! So basically just by looking at the fact that the sequence is made up by independent R.V. and the $\sum_{n=1} \mathcal{P}(X_n=1) = \infty $, I can always say that there's no convergence to 0 almost surely? I'm asking just to understand If I understood :)

Comment: Well there are pathological examples, for example if you have independent random variables $X_n$ that can only be $1$ $(\mathbb{P}(X_n=1)=1 \forall n)$. Then the sum $\sum\mathbb{P}(X_n=1)=\infty$, but there is a.s. convergence to $X\equiv 1$. All that B-C lemma says is that with probability $1$ you will get infinitely many ones in your sequence. I hope it's a bit clearer.

Comment: I'm sorry to bothering you again, but I want to clear out one thing. In the exercise presented by me I simply found that the upper bound found by chebyshev inequality is $\infty$, basically it's like if I have not found any upper bound. But is this enough?

Comment: Notice that it doesn't tell us anything; if $a\leq \infty$, then $a$ can be either finite or infinite, to this 'bound' is a bit useless to us :) The important part is that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(X_n=1) = \infty$, which allows us to use B-C lemma.

Comment: But in this case who is $\sum_{n=1} \mathcal{P}(X_n=1)= \infty$? Because if it's the RHS of the equation it would be ok, but if it's the LHS we can't say anything I suppose . Again, sorry!

Comment: I'm a bit confused a bit by the question. Let's just say that in this case, when we want to show that there is no almost surely convergence, using Chebyshev inequality like that is not a good way to go about it.

Comment: I try to explain myself better. In this case I used the Chebyshev's inequality in order to find $\sum \frac{1}{n*\epsilon^2}$ and by seeing that this goes to $\infty$, I could apply the B-C Lemma and say that there's no convergence a.s. But i want to pindown: is this summation that tells my that there's no convergence?

Comment: No. This summation from Chebyshev's inequality doesn't tell us anything, because it's a upper bound. So you can't apply B-C lemma. But you can use it if you follow my reasoning from the answer.

Comment: Perfect, clear that. My last question is, since this doesn't derive from Chebyshev, from where do I understand that "$\sum P(X_n=1) =\infty)$?

Comment: As per your definition, $P(X_n=1)=\frac{1}{n}$, so $\sum P(X_n=1)=\sum \frac{1}{n}=\infty.$ :)

Comment: Thank you! So using the upper bound found with chebyshev would be a good choice only in the case this is finite :)